# Parsing away the history of emails

Tags: regex, vba, email, parsing

I am working on a project where we want to parse emails and save the body/text in a database for later use in a different format, such as a page on a website.
When an email is sent and the parsing process executes, the body is read by the code. The annoying problem however is, when an user answers an email by pressing on the reply button, most emailing platforms (outlook, gmail, ...) add the history of the conversation on the bottom of the email. This text is unneccassary, as it is already saved in the database from the mail before. As such, this text needs to be deleted before being saved.

Currently I am using regex to find the start of the history to trim it away.

```
Dim regexes = New List(Of Regex)() From {
       New Regex("From:(.*) \[mailto:" + Regex.Escape(email) + "\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Outlook
       New Regex("Van:(.*) \[mailto:" + Regex.Escape(email) + "\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Outlook
       New Regex("Van:(.*) \[mailnaar:" + Regex.Escape(email) + "\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Outlook
       New Regex("From:\s*" + Regex.Escape(email), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Algemeen 
       New Regex("<" + Regex.Escape(email) + ">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Algemeen 'Is potentieel te breed! 
       New Regex("Op(.*)schreef(.*)<(\n)?" + Regex.Escape(email) + ">:", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline), 'Gmail
       New Regex(Regex.Escape(email) + "\s+wrote:", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Gmail/Algemeen
       New Regex("Op.*(\r\n)?schreef.*<(\r)?(\n)?" + Regex.Escape(email) + ">:", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline), 'Gmail
       New Regex("\n.*On.*(\r\n)?wrote:\r\n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline), 'Gmail
       New Regex("-+original\s+message-+\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Algemeen
       New Regex("from:\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Algemeen
       New Regex("^>.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline), 'Algemeen op basis van > (=tab voor geschiedenis)
       New Regex("(.*)<(\r)?(\n)?" + Regex.Escape(email) + ">:$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Gmail als hij verkleinde versie gebruikt
       New Regex("(.*)<(\r)?(\n)?(.*)>:", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Gmail als hij verkleinde versie gebruikt
       New Regex("________________________________(\r)?(\n)From: ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Hotmail
       New Regex("----- Oorspronkelijk bericht -----(\r)?(\n)?(\r)?(\n)?Van: ""(.*)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), 'Telenet
       New Regex("----- Original message -----(\r)?(\n)?(\r)?(\n)?From: ""(.*)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) 'Telenet
   }

    Dim index = text.Length

    For Each regex__1 As Regex In regexes
        Dim match = regex__1.Match(text)

        If match.Success AndAlso match.Index < index Then
            index = match.Index
        End If
    Next

    Return text.Substring(0, index).Trim()
```

But, depending on the email platform, the required regex is different as they start the history using other words or are in a different language.

My question is: how can I generalise this as much as possible? I can not test all the different email platforms and languages.

One way would be to add something detectable myself to the top of the email, such as:

~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-
Reply above
~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-

which will always be trimmed, removing the history underneath it, but for some email platforms, it might still leave the "from / to" text as it is put above the line.

Comment: Can't you do it using an XML-parser and check for the quote part. From a quick look I noticed that gmail starts it with a `div` tag with the attribute `class="gmail_quote"`. Outlook appears to have a line made from a `div` with a more complex `style` attribute, but it could be possible to detect.

Comment: Found [this at github](https://github.com/mailgun/talon). Maybe it can help you? Checking the file "quotations.py" may give you ideas on "rules" to detect quotes.